# Giving html list elements that only contain a specified text a background color using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html script:

```
<ul>
<li class="container">
<div class="age">24</div>
<div class="married">no</div>
</li>

<li class="container">
<div class="age">27</div>
<div class="married">yes</div>
</li>

<li class="container">
<div class="age">56</div>
<div class="married"><!--empty--></div>
</li>

<li class="container">
<div class="age">34</div>
<div class="married">no</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

I would like that only the `li` elements that contain a `no` in their `div.married` get a green background using Jquery.

I don't understand why [this code](http://jsbin.com/urodit/144/edit) does not work. How do I get the intended result?

Comment: The code you have is only applying to the **first** matched element when you call `mar.text()`, but `mar.parent().css(...);` will be applied to **all** matched elements. So if the first one has "no" in the `<div>` then they'll all be made green.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an erroneous `;` after `"green"` although you would still not get what your looking for.

You could also;

```
$(".married:contains(no)").parent().css(...)
```

Comment: What would you write to color every list item that **contains anything but** `no`?

Comment: `$(".married").not(":contains(no)").parent().css(...)`

Comment: `:contains` is deprecated in css 3 according to [this article](http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors/). Although it is still available for Jquery I wonder how long you will still be able to use it.

Comment: jQuery's `contains` is implemented in JS so its not related to the CSS pseudo selector at all.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$(".container .married").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == "no";
}).closest('.container').css('background-color', 'green');
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/dQNvU/1/)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$(function(){
  $(".married").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() === 'no') {
      $(this).closest('li').addClass('highlight')
    }

  });   
});
```

and the CSS class

```
.highlight {
   background: green;
}
```

it's better to always keep off css from javascript whenever it is possible

example: http://jsbin.com/irubap/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
$("li:contains('no')").css('background-color', 'green');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var mar = $(".married").filter( function( index, element ) { 
  return $( element ).text().match( /no/g );
}).css( 'background-color', 'green' );
```